# How to modify the Info,plist of a third-party framework in XCODE (imported using CocoaPods)?

Tags: ios, xcode

Submissions to Apple's App Store result in errors due to third party framework missing key-value pairs in framework. (The Info.plist file is missing the required key: CFBundleShortVersionString).

I was able to fix by opening the xcarchive files and making the additions myself.

However, is there an easy way to do this so I don't need to do it with every archived submission?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. Turns out you just use Finder and navigate to the project -> pods folder and find the framework.